# perl - "tee" the qx operator

Tags: perl, redirect

I'm working on a script that currently has:

```
my @files = `$some_command`;
print @files;
chomp @files;
foreach my $file (@files)
{
    process($file);
}
```

It works correctly, but the `some_command` part takes the majority of the script's time.  And during that time, nothing appears on stdout, because Perl has redirected output from `some_command` to populate the `@files` array.  It only gets printed when `some_command` is done and Perl moves on to `print @files;`.

Is there some clever way to change this code so that the output of `some_command` appears as it is executing?  I could maybe try something like this using `tee(1)`:

```
my $tmpfile = File::Temp->new();
system("$some_command | tee " . $tmpfile->filename);
my @files;
{ local $/ = undef; @files = split /\s/, <$tmpfile>; }
```

But I'd rather avoid the temporary file stuff if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: Have you tried unbuffering output?    $| = 1;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could open the handle and manually populate the array yourself while printing the lines as you go.

Something like this would probably work,

```
  open my $fh, '-|', $some_command;
  while(<$fh>)
  {
    print $_;
    push @files, $_;
  }
  close $fh;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could skip the `qx()` operator and open a filehandle to the process's output stream directly. This code in functionally equivalent to `my @files = qx($some_command)`:

```
 my @files = ();
 open my $proc_fh, "$some_command |";
 while (<$proc_fh>) {
     push @files, $_;
 }
 close $proc_fh;
```

but inside the while loop you can do whatever you want with `$_`:

```
 while (<$proc_fh>) {
     print "INPUT: $_\n";
     push @files, $_;
 }
```

An important consideration is the output buffering behavior of `$some_command`. If that command buffers its output, then your `$proc_fh` handle will not receive any input until a large block of data is available.

Answer (score 1):

The [`File::Tee`](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/File-Tee-0.06/lib/File/Tee.pm) module looks like it could do what you want. There are examples there of redirecting STDOUT when running `system()`. I haven't used it, so I can't give more concrete examples, but it looks like this would be a good jumping-off point for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also open your command as a file descriptor and read the output as the command is producing it.  Something like this (taken from http://www.netadmintools.com/art269.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (PINGTEST, "/bin/ping  -c 5 netadmintools.com |");
$i=1;
while (<PINGTEST>){
print "Line # ".$i." ".$_;
$i++;
}
print "All done!\n";
close PINGTEST;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture%3a%3aTiny) is probably exactly what you want.

```
   use Capture::Tiny qw/ tee tee_merged /;

   ($stdout, $stderr) = tee {
     # your code here
   };

   $merged = tee_merged {
     # your code here
   };
```